# Regex to change two last character after space in synced textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to change last two characters after space on keyup event but i want to change only in the second `textarea (#ta_2)`. It changes only if i affect the modified value on the first typing `textarea (#ta_1`). How can i do it ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
    var text = $(this).val().replace(/ (ak)+$/g, " AK");
    //$("#ta_1").val(text);
    $("#ta_2").val(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the old school `indexOf()`, `lastIndexOf()` and `slice()` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var start = text.lastIndexOf(' ak')
        // we take the last occurence of ' ak' in the string
        // and replace if with ' AK'
        if( text.indexOf(' ak') > -1)
            text = text.slice(0,start) + ' AK' + text.slice(start+3)
        // we set the second textarea value
        $("#ta_2").val(text);
    });
});
```

And [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cl3MM/wr0u4yta/)

**Edit**

Replace `text = text.slice(0,start) + ' AK' + text.slice(start+3)` by `text = text.replace(/ ak/g, ' AK')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if( text.indexOf(' ak') > -1)
            text = text.replace(/ ak/g, ' AK')
        // we set the second textarea value
        $("#ta_2").val(text);
    });
});
```

See [update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cl3MM/wr0u4yta/1/)

Comment: What do you mean not working? if I type 'xxx ak' in the first textarea in the fiddle, it sets the second textarea to 'xxx AK'. Isn'it what you want?

Comment: @yes but it changes after space sir :( i want it stable

Comment: Do you mean when you type `xxx ak xxx ak` then the second textarea should be `xxx AK xxx AK`?

Comment: then change  the `text =text....` line by : `text = text.replace(/ ak/g, ' AK')`. See edit